# Prove that $X \cap (Y \cap Z) = (X \cap Y) \cap Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question about sets, I need to prove that: $$X \cap (Y \cap Z)  = (X \cap Y) \,\cap \,Z$$ I tried to do something like this: $$1. \; X \cap (Y \cap Z) = \{a: a \in X\} \cap \{a: a \in Y \land a \in Z \}$$ $$2. \;= \{a: a \in X \land a \in Y \land a \in Z \}$$ $$3\;=\{a: \in X \land a \in Y \} \cap \{a: a \in Z\}$$ $$4. \; = (X \cap Y) \cap Z$$ I will be glad to hear what should I do after that, or how can I understand if my attempt was success?

Comment: Choose $x \in X \cap (Y \cap Z)$. Your argument essentially shows that this $x$ must also be in $(X \cap Y) \cap Z$ (i.e. $X \cap (Y \cap Z) \subset (X \cap Y) \cap Z$). Now show the reverse and you should be done.

Comment: You can also make a truth table for both, and if they are exactly the same, then $X \cap (Y \cap Z) \Leftrightarrow (X \cap Y) \cap Z$.  I think this is the most straightforward approach to proving statements like this.

Comment: Yeah, truth table was so easy, that's really great tool, I just realized :D and thanks guys.